# Override CSS Classes Infinitely

Tags: html, css

This is more of a theoretical question.

Is the stack of overrides for CSS ad-infinitum? For instance, is there always a CSS override for every override?

Lets say I have written this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <style>
      .a {
        color: red;
      }
      /* Override it again */
      div.a {
        color: blue;
      }
      /* Again! */
      body div.a {
        color: yellow;
      }
      /* Again!! :) */
      html body div.a {
        color: yellow;
      }
      /* AND AGAIN!! */
      html body div.a {
        color: pink !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="a">a</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is `!important` combined with `html body div.a` the absolute highest level override for `div.a`?
Must there always exist something with a higher override?

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory you can simply repeat a rule to increase the specificity.

```
.foo.foo.foo { }
```

In practise, browsers eventually treat a selector as having too many components and ignore it.

(There is also the style attribute, which is more specific than any selector)

Answer (score 0):

inline styling with `!important` applied is the highest override I've ever used.

Example:
`<div class="a" style="color: blue !important">a</div>` Will override all other css applied

Answer (score 0):

If you declare an inline style rule for `div.a` with the `!important` declaration it'll still override the rule declared in the `<style>` tag.

Any inline rule generally over-qualifies internally or externally declared styles, regardless of the number of selectors used to specify that rule. The only time an inline rule is over-qualified by internal or external styles is when the `!important` declaration is used - but if that declaration is used on an inline style you want to overwrite you'll be cursing.

In this case you'd need to apply some javascript to reset the attribute.